# TCPDF grey background for few cells?

Tags: php, pdf, cakephp, pdf-generation, tcpdf

I'm using TCPDF in CakePHP and trying to make some background (grey) for few cells. Well here the idea:

[image]

so the grey thing would somehow have to be define outside of the cells containg text.

Any ideas?
Paul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest way is to deliver your content as HTML with some simple formating included.

Check example 6 from [TCPDF examples](https://tcpdf.org/examples.php)

Answer (score 10):

try this.

```
$this -> TCPDF -> SetFillColor(249,249,249); // Grey
$this -> TCPDF -> Cell(95,$cellHigh,$data,'L',0,'L',$fill,'',0,false,'T','C');
```

The [TCPDF example No. 5](https://tcpdf.org/examples.php) will give you different background colors.

Answer (score 0):

**TCPDF** has the habit of changing the background color to GREY when it comes across Tables in the HTML when generating the PDF.

The HTML will be usually having this background color tag for table.

```
background-color:transparent
```

whicih makes **TCPDF** to make it GREY. A simple fix would be just replacing the HTML content with  whichever color you like. An example using PHP

```
$html = str_replace("background-color:transparent","background-color:white", $html);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the below code:

```
<td style="background-color:red;">
  Your Data...
</td>
```

Comment: This question is about TCPDF, a PDF building PHP library not HTML. Also using `red` instead of a color code might have some side effects.